# how to remove object from array using javascript or angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to remove object from array and get the resulted array.I am using remove function but it is not working perfectly 
Here is my input

I need to remove all value of array which have `"file": "Id"`

here is my fiddle

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; i < arr[i].columns.length; i++)
    arr[i].columns[0].remove()
}
```

Comment: U could try it easily!! refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-an-array

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this function to remove all value of array which have `"file": "Id"`

```
for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
    for (var k=0; k < arr[i].columns.length; k++){
        if(arr[i].columns[k].fieldNameOrPath == 'Id'){
            arr[i].columns.splice(k,1)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight error in incrementing `k`

```
for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
    for (var k=0; k<arr[i].columns.length;k++)
    delete arr[i].columns[0]
}
```

[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9cLL4hh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

```
var result = _.map(arr, function(obj){ 
                return {
                    columns: _.reject(obj['columns'], function(innerObj){
                                return innerObj['fieldNameOrPath'] == 'Id';
                            })
                }
            });
```